# Typescript object fields keys generically

Tags: typescript, generics, union

I have a data structure that contains various optional fields with different types that have to be fetched individually and formatted. The formatting functions take concrete values.

I tried doing something like the following minimal working example, but it errors with with `Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Data[P]'`.

I understand why the problem happens, but I want to make this work. I quick hack would be to cast `data[idx][key]` as `Optional<T>`, but can this be done without type casts?

```ts
// In my code this is more complex, a simple `T | undefined` doesn't work.
type Optional<T> = { kind: 'none' } | { kind: 'value', value: T};

interface Data {
  name: Optional<string>;
  id: Optional<number>;
}

function computeIndex(): number {
  // Some logic here
  return 0;
}

// Format field `key` of `data` using `formatter`.
// Use default `def` if the value is `none`.
function printField<
  P extends keyof Data,
  T extends Data[P] extends Optional<infer V> ? V : never
>(data: Data[], key: P, formatter: (val: T) => string, def: T): string {
  const idx = computeIndex();

  const field = data[idx][key];

  switch (field.kind) {
    case 'none':
      return formatter(def);

    case 'value':
      return formatter(field.value);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is a cast-free solution at present.

Ultimately, TS seems to have trouble inferring `Optional<string | number>` from `Optional<string> | Optional<number>` in the `field` declaration, so we give it the extra nudge in the form of the `Optional<T>` cast.

Is this a hack? If you view it as working around the TS checker's inference limitations, maybe. I would agree it was a hack if it opened the door to mistyping values, or if the result didn't work as well as desired

But the end result works as well as a "non-hack" solution, in that it correctly type-checks `formatter` given `key`. And I don't see how the cast could result in the wrong type of value making it through.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I decided to not waste any more time on this and just use a cast :D